# Strange behaviour of conditions in PHP

Tags: php, if-statement, behavior

I'm wondering why is output of the following code:

```
$a = log(5, 5);
$b = round(log(5, 5));
echo 'a: ';
var_dump($a);
echo '<br>';
echo 'b: ';
var_dump($b);
echo '<br>';
echo ($a == $b) ? 'equal' : 'not equal';
```

this

```
a: float(1) 
b: float(1) 
not equal
```

Thanks to anyone who can explain this to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just to quote the chapter [**Floating point numbers**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php) from the PHP manual:

> Warning Floating point precision
>
> Floating point numbers have limited precision. Although it depends on
>   the system, PHP typically uses the IEEE 754 double precision format,
>   which will give a maximum relative error due to rounding in the order
>   of 1.11e-16. Non elementary arithmetic operations may give larger
>   errors, and, of course, error propagation must be considered when
>   several operations are compounded.
>
> Additionally, rational numbers that are exactly representable as
>   floating point numbers in base 10, like 0.1 or 0.7, do not have an
>   exact representation as floating point numbers in base 2, which is
>   used internally, no matter the size of the mantissa. Hence, they
>   cannot be converted into their internal binary counterparts without a
>   small loss of precision. This can lead to confusing results: for
>   example, floor((0.1+0.7)*10) will usually return 7 instead of the
>   expected 8, since the internal representation will be something like
>   7.9999999999999991118....
>
> **So never trust floating number results to the last digit, and do not
>   compare floating point numbers directly for equality.** If higher
>   precision is necessary, the arbitrary precision math functions and gmp
>   functions are available.

Comment: on the same page:

    <?php
    $a = 1.23456789;
    $b = 1.23456780;
    $epsilon = 0.00001;

    if(abs($a-$b) < $epsilon) {
       echo "true";
    }
    ?>

Comment: How is (1.01 == 1.01) true then?

Comment: @kustrle - Because you've built a comparison where the binary IEEE 754 representation of both operands is the same bit to bit, probably by just typing two float literals. That's of little use in real life--you don't normally want to deal with base-2 digits when coding in PHP.

Comment: But shouldn't var_dump output something like "a: float(1.000000000000000001)" then?

Comment: @kustrle - You're still missing the point. var_dump() converts from binary to decimal, truncates to X digits and prints the result. But computers do math with binary digits.

Comment: Thanks for explaination. I understand that computers operate in binary. What I didn't know was that var_dump truncates digits.